# How to stop and remove running movieClip which is dynamically created

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I am new to flash/AS2, and was trying to make a youtube video gallery in flash AS2.0. I've created one movieClip with name "**video_mc**" and creating child clips inside, to **load youtube movies on release of buttons** ("**video_btn01**" and "**video_btn02**"). Here is my code.

```
var vidId:String = "";

function createMovieInstance(mid){
    var mclip:MovieClip = video_mc.createEmptyMovieClip("v", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
    mclip.loadMovie("http://www.youtube.com/v/"+mid+"&autoplay=0");
}

video_btn01.onRelease = function(){
    vidId = "iRaR7O1wNGg";
    createMovieInstance(vidId);
}
video_btn02.onRelease = function(){
    vidId = "h22OsQONU3M";
    createMovieInstance(vidId);
}
```

Movies are getting loaded properly, but the first loaded movie will be playing in background while the next is getting loaded, because i'm creating another clild movie clip and loading the second movie, while the first one is getting played in another movieClip instance. So need to find the running movieClip and unload it. It would be great if somebody can assist me how to overcome this issue. Cheers!..

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, and let me know.

```
 function createMovieInstance(mid){
    if(video_mc.v != undefined){
        video_mc.v.unloadMovie();
        //If the Depth is above or below the limit this will help you
        video_mc.v.swapDepths(0);
        video_mc.v.removeMovieClip();
    }
    var mclip:MovieClip = video_mc.createEmptyMovieClip("v", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
    mclip.loadMovie("http://www.youtube.com/v/"+mid+"&autoplay=0");
}
```

Comment: Dear friend, Thanks for the quick reply.. :-) But unfortunately its not working. First link will work properly, and after when we start playing the youtube video and click on the second video link, the second video is getting loaded but the first movie sound is getting increased and playing in the same time. Its not visibile but playing in the background. May be in some other movieClip in a lower depth. Second movie will come and can be played also. But then its getting messed up, the video player starts flickering... :-( can you please suggest any other alternate method. Thanks dear!